# How to create a cgi page with button to post to another page

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl cgi page. It should have a textbox and a submit button. When the submit button is clicked it should POST values to another cgi page, where the values will be collected through param. I know how to create the page using html. But need help in doing so using cgi. The following is the code I have. The problem is it posts to itself. But it needs to post to a different page.

```
print header,
start_html('Query GenBank With an Accession Number'),
h1('Query GenBank With an Accession Number'),
p,
h3('Please enter a valid Name'),
p,
hr,
start_multipart_form,
'Name' , textfield('Name'), p,
submit, reset, p,
hr,
end_form;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `start_multipart_form` method accepts parameters that will help.  Try this:

```
...,
start_multipart_form( -method=>'POST', -action=>$url ),
...
```

Just set the `$url` variable to your other CGI page.  See [this](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#STARTING-AND-ENDING-A-FORM) for more details.